# PHP Return in function Fedex

Tags: php, function, return, fedex

Dont know if I should add to this post or not but it is kind of relevant I think

This works just fine

```
function getProperty($var)
{
    if($var == 'check') 
        Return true;

    if($var == 'shipaccount') 
        Return '286096425543324';
```

But this does not? How would one enter a

```
$fedex_account = "286096425543324";
function getProperty($var)
{
    if($var == 'check') 
        Return true;

    if($var == 'shipaccount') 
        Return '$fedex_account';
```

Comment: why do you want to single quote the variable if it has nothing else to attach with? Return just a variable shouldn't need to be single quoted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
'$fedex_account'
```

Single quotes don't expand variables. Just do this:

```
function getProperty($var){
// You need this if $fedex_account is a global variable
global $fedex_account;
if($var == 'check') Return true;
if($var == 'shipaccount') Return $fedex_account;
```

Comment: @Michael Howey Your `$fedex_account` variable may be declared globally, so you either need to pass it in or use the `global` statement as shown in the updated code

Comment: @OZ_ globals aren't all that evil. However I fear trying to explain my stance will lead to a very long thread that I'd rather avoid

Comment: THANK YOU :) This has always been such an issue of mind. Passing info into an array from a database.

Comment: Are Globals bad? I dont really see how doing it this way could cause an issue?

Comment: @Michael Howey It's a bit of a touchy subject. Globals are often frowned upon because you're utilizing them makes it so functions do not have a definite state. However, they are sometimes useful for keeping configuration variables like database connection strings, or account numbers in your case.

Comment: @Michael: global variables are almost always bad.  Pretty much the only time they're acceptable is for simple stuff like this.  If you move into something more advanced, you won't use them at all.

Comment: @Michael Howey The alternative is to pass the variable around, but that can get tricky as you have to balance code readability with keeping your functions pure. The debate around it can get fairly heated, so I generally try to not touch too much on the matter.

Comment: @Michael Howey, yes. With using globals your code will be bugged, will be the splinter in refactoring and this code can not be reused.

Comment: @onteria_ you if don't want to discuss it - just don't do it. Don't give bad advices to newbies.

Comment: I write huge programs and I have never really ran in to a need to use globals. I wish someone could give a reason on why they would hurt in a simple Fedex function. Or better yet an example of a better way to do it without globals

Comment: @Michael Howey You might want to take a look at `define` instead for creating named constants (as a Fedex number is a value that won't get changed after you define it): http://us3.php.net/define . However it still has the inherit weakness of a global, which is that your function is not completely encapsulated, and uses a value outside of arguments and local function scope. Another option is to pass the value around various functions, which means updating some of your function signatures.

Comment: @Michael Howey, it means you do it wrong. Always, when you want to write `global` - it's symptom of bad design. I wrote already, why globals are bad, you don't want to read it. As example - try to call your function from script, where $fedex_account not defined. You'll see, that your function can be called from 1 script only - it's first and not last effect of using globals.

Comment: @OZ, To say I do something wrong that I don't do is silly. Give an example of a way to do it right. Can I kill the global after inseting it like $fedex_account = '';

Answer (score 3):

Read about [Visibility](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php) - `$fedex_account` are in other scope.
and about [quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php).